# Good book for finite sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, reference-request

Is there a good introductory book about finding closed forms of finite sums? I know Concrete Mathematics has a chapter on it but I was wondering if there is a more extensive resource.

**EDIT:** My question is about finite series, while the alleged duplicates are about infinite series.

Comment: Also see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456312/introductory-book-on-series?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494518/book-on-infinite-series?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754954/any-good-books-for-infinite-series?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068101/good-book-for-convergence-of-series?rq=1

Comment: @Moo My question is about finite series; unfortunately all those possible duplicates are about inifnite series

Comment: I think you will find that both are covered, for example: Introduction To Finite And Infinite Series And Related Topics
by J.H. Heinbockel

Comment: A series is (by definition) an *infinite* sum. Do you mean simply finite sums? And what do you want to know about them? Techniques for finding closed forms?

Comment: @Ovi: Also, maybe you mean things in The Summation of Series by Harold T. Davis and Summation of Series by L.B.W. Jolley and Computational Techniques for the Summation of Series by Anthony Sofo

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes I mean finite sums and yes I am looking for techniques for finding closed forms.

Comment: @Moo Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: IIRC the bibliography in Concrete Mathematics points you at [A=B](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html).